# Can TortoiseGit be configured to perform a background fetch?

Tags: git, version-control, tortoisegit, git-fetch

As a development team we are moving from a centralized source control system (TFS) to using Git. One issue developers have is with the tooling. We have been quite impressed with TortoiseGit and I personally loved working with TortoiseSVN at another company but have found one usability issue; you are not informed via any part of the GUI that there are changes to pull from a repository we are tracking.

Is there a way to enable such a feature in TortoiseGit? As my question suggests the mechanical way to achieve this would be to perform a periodic background fetch but it would be good if the tool had a built in mechanism to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible in TortoiseGit. I use the tool [SCM Notifier](https://github.com/pocorall/scm-notifier) to get notified about changes in git repositories.

Answer (score 1):

Can't do it for now. Please see [TortoiseGit issue 2296](https://tortoisegit.org/issue/2296).